# Collapse a responsive table layout using divs to 2 columns on small screens

Tags: html, css

Currently have the below div table created, How do I get columns |3| and |4| to go under |1| and |2| respectively, dependent on width.

Current result:
|1| |2| |3| |4|
|1| |2| |3| |4|

Desired result:
|1| |2|
|1| |2|
|3| |4|
|3| |4|

or
|1| |2|
|3| |4|
|1| |2|
|3| |4|

```css
.product-info-table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.product-info-table-body {
    display: table-row-group;
}

.product-info-table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.product-info-table-cell {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="product-info-table">
    <div class="product-info-table-body">
        <div class="product-info-table-row">
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-info-table-row">
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text</div>
        </div>
              <div class="product-info-table-row">
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text</div>
        </div>
              <div class="product-info-table-row">
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading</div>
            <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries to detect the screen width and then use [**grid layout**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) instead of **table layout** on small screens.

I'd also suggest adding the CSS for "**mobile-first**" i.e. the default CSS is for mobile displays, and then detect larger screens in the media query and apply your table table layout. To do this:

1. Add CSS for grid layout on the `product-info-table-row` - the rest of the divs just need the default display, so you don't need to add anything else (except any styling you want to apply, e.g. borders on the cells)

   ```
   .product-info-table-row {
     display: grid;
     /* Display as 2 columns: col 1 has width 30%, col 2 is allocated the rest */
     grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
   }
   ```
2. Wrap you existing table layout css in a suitable media query, e.g.

   ```
   @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
       /* Your existing table-display CSS goes here */
   }
   ```

**That's it! Working Example:**

```css
.product-info-table-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
}

.product-info-table-cell {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .product-info-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-info-table-body {
    display: table-row-group;
  }
  .product-info-table-row {
    display: table-row;
  }
  .product-info-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-info-table">
  <div class="product-info-table-body">
    <div class="product-info-table-row">
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading 1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text 1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading 2</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-table-row">
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading 1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text 1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading 2</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-table-row">
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading 1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text 1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading 2</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info-table-row">
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading 1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text 1</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Heading 2</div>
      <div class="product-info-table-cell">Text 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you again, very explanatory answers to learn from. I got a question, I implemented the code (already made styling), the collapsed table is looking weird. https://codepen.io/Newbie1122/pen/rNeGQaO

Comment: @josh You need to copy the styles for the appearance outside of the media query also, e.g. borders, colours, padding etc for `.product-info-table-cell-heading` and `.product-info-table-cell-text`. And don't forget to remove the width - let the grid CSS handle that. It was `grid-template-columns: auto auto;` which meant 2 equal columns, I've updated the answer to be to `grid-template-columns: 30% auto;` which is 30% to the first column and the second column takes the rest of the space.